# Ajax post with a file return

Tags: java, ajax, spring, file, post

Is there a way to return a dynamically server-side generated file, which was fetched from a ajax post structure?

Writing a small web mvc project, which generates a list of data(the data is generated from a complex aggregation query and cannot be called from id or whatsoever), and come up to the part on which i want to export some selected parts to a file and download it.

How does it work:
1. On the page i select some fields with key data(using JQuery DataTable)
2. Send it to a controller(Spring to be precise)
3. Generate a bytestream and return it as a HTTPResponse with "Content-disposition", "attachment" header.

Thing is that i select the lines and form the needed data using JQuery->Ajax, so the result of the Controller->Post stays inside the javascript part, not giving me a "Save as...".

I'm already thinking of a temporary directory or something, but saving option for the last.

Comment: Unfortunately No....

Comment: But can i somehow do a non-ajax post, that should open a new tab\window and recieve a normal server reply, which will directly recieve the file?

Comment: obviously.. you can post form... if content is downloadable file then will popup for downlaod or auto download start without loosing your current page.

Comment: thats something. Now to figure out how to generate a hidden form, put a JSON in it, and post it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not get file through ajax, but you can achieve it by generate form dynamically and submit it. As per our comment discussion for generate form and submit it you can do something like this.

```
function autoSubmitForm(method, url, post_data) {
    var element = document.getElementById("virtual_form");
    if(element != null )
    {
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("id", "virtual_form");
    form.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    form.method = method;
    form.action = url;   
    for(i in post_data)
    {
         var element=document.createElement("input");
         element.value=post_data[i];
         element.name=i;
         form.appendChild(element); 
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

}

autoSubmitForm('POST','your_url.php',{id:"xyz",other_input:"input value"});
```

Here `{id:"xyz",other_input:"input value"}` is object of post data you can define it dynamically pair of field name and value of field. pass it in function.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that now

Comment: meanwhile I edited from my code. :) so please check my edits

Comment: I dont think url argument will not work in this function.. because we can pass url as we want. and in function we can pass method is GET or POST

Comment: @AntonTsyhanenko, is this working for you?, if yes then mark as correct and up vote please.

Comment: to be fair it didnt. Made a workaround using session scopes and reffering to virtual id of a document to get the normal file return(using the session scope i managed to cut down the sql queries to a minimum). Still thanks for the help.