# How to excute wkhtmltopdf command using ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, shell, command, exec

I have create a wp_ajax function and calling this function on button click. In ajax function i have added a command for excute wkhtmltopdf libarary but my code is not working. Please check.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_genratepdf', 'genratepdf' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_genratepdf', 'genratepdf' );

function genratepdf(){

    shell_exec("wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com /dir-path/pdf38.pdf");

    die('Y');
}
```

Jquery Code:

```
jQuery("#myBtnPdf").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var divContents = jQuery(".pf-content").html();
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: { action: "genratepdf", content:divContents },
            success:
            function(data) {

            }
       });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but Try with

```
function genratepdf(){
    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;
    $pdf_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR. $ds. "xyz.pdf";
    exec ("wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com ".$pdf_path);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($pdf_path).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf_path));
    ob_clean();
    readfile($pdf_path);
    die();

}
```

it will create pdf file into wordpress content directory

In Javascript code

```
function autoSubmitForm(method, url, post_data) {
    var element = document.getElementById("virtual_form");
    if(element != null )
    {
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("id", "virtual_form");
    form.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    form.method = method;
    form.action = url;   
    for(i in post_data)
    {
         var element=document.createElement("input");
         element.value=post_data[i];
         element.name=i;
         form.appendChild(element); 
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);

}


jQuery("#myBtnPdf").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var divContents = jQuery(".pf-content").html();

    autoSubmitForm('POST',ajaxurl,{action:"genratepdf",content:divContents});
});
```

Comment: But how i can get the download popup for save pdf

Comment: unfortunately...in ajax request you can not get download popup

Comment: can you show me your ajax code, so I can help to you.

Comment: Jquery Ajax is added

Comment: Can you show me your code please.. how jQuery AJAX added? if like my help please do upvote also :)

Comment: Check above Jquery Code. Do do upvote also for question

Comment: Please follow my answer on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789610/ajax-post-with-a-file-return/38790288#38790288 you can use that function which is alternative to ajax

Comment: I have updated code for remove form if  virtual form already exist... also please let me know if this trick working or not?